# Как убрать запятые в массиве

Tags: python, list

Как из этого `['a', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A']`
Сделать это `["aa", "Aa", "aA", "AA"]`
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку слева от него, чтобы принять.

Answer (score 3):

Так, например:

```
lst = ['a', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A']
result = []
for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
    result.append(lst[i] + lst[i + 1])
print(result)
```